# Building a sort of digital clock C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a digital clock in unity. I´ve got the seconds hours and minutes hands working correctly using `TimeSpan` in C#.

I couldn't figure out how to also use `DateTime.Month` in the same script as the script that controls time of day.

So I decided to make a script just covering the Month arm of the calendar but it wont move.

I've included both the default clock script and the months arm script.

Any help making the months script work would be awesome, I cant figure it out. Or a good way to combine the two scripts into one would be cool.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
//only calls Time of day!!!!

public class Clock : MonoBehaviour {

    const float
        degreesPerHour = 30f,
        degreesPerMinute = 6f,
        degreesPerSecond = 6f;

    public Transform hoursTransform, minutesTransform, secondsTransform;

    public bool continuous;

    void Update () {
        if (continuous) {
            UpdateContinuous();
        }
        else {
            UpdateDiscrete();
        }
    }

    void UpdateContinuous () {
        TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        hoursTransform.localRotation =
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, (float)time.TotalHours * degreesPerHour, 0f);
        minutesTransform.localRotation =
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, (float)time.TotalMinutes * degreesPerMinute, 0f);
        secondsTransform.localRotation =
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, (float)time.TotalSeconds * degreesPerSecond, 0f);
    }

    void UpdateDiscrete () {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        hoursTransform.localRotation =
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, time.Hour * degreesPerHour, 0f);
        minutesTransform.localRotation =
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, time.Minute * degreesPerMinute, 0f);
        secondsTransform.localRotation =
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, time.Second * degreesPerSecond, 0f);
    }
}
```

script for sec min and hour hands

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
//only calls Month!

public class Months : MonoBehaviour
{

    const float
        degreesPerMonth = 30f;

    public Transform monthsTransform;

    public bool continuous;

    void Update()
    {
        if (continuous)
        {
            UpdateContinuous();
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateDiscrete();
        }
    }

    void UpdateContinuous()
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Today;

        monthsTransform.localRotation =
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, (float) time.Month * degreesPerMonth, 0f);
    }

    void UpdateDiscrete()
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

        monthsTransform.localRotation =
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, time.Month * degreesPerMonth, 0f);
    }
}
```

broken script thats supposed to make the months hand point to the right month on the clock

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not intended to teach you programming. That's what books, Google and tutorials are for. So, please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please post the code in the question as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We should not have to go looking for it at other sites.

Comment: Do you intend the "month" arm to move faster in shorter months (for "continuous")? If not, I'd suggest calculating the total minutes (or seconds? however fine a resolution you want) for the current year (something like `(new DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1) - new DateTime(year, 1, 1)).TotalMinutes` and then get the currently elapsed ones (`(now - startOfYear).TotalMinutes`) and calculate the needed degrees from there.

Comment: Please don't link off to other sites with content that should be included as part of your question. Always put it in-line.

Comment: The number of degrees per month is not a constant since a month can have 28,29,30,or 31 days.